# Display table names

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular, ssas-2012, ssas-2016

I have a tabular model cube with Compatability Level SQL Server 2016. I assigned the columns and the measures in two different display folders.
When analyzing the cube with Excel, the columns and the measures are displayed in two different display folders, But they appear under the table name.
I want to rename the table name for the columns to "Codes" and the table name for dimensions to "Values."

Is it possible to do that?
I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Why not name your Display Folders "Codes" and "Values"?

Another option would be to access your values through measures (eg. `Total = SUM('Data Table'[Total])` ) , which you could put in any table, and then hide the values in the original table.